# The Type signature lacks an appropriate binding [Haskell]

Tags: haskell, types, compilation

I have been googling around to find the answer, and even came to a few questions asked here. It seems that this is an ambiguous error and I can't figure out how to solve it in my instance.

The offending code is below:

```
pos :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> Int
pos [] _ = -1
pos (x:xs) y
| not $ elem y (x:xs) = -1
| x == y =  0
| otherwise = 1 + pos xs y

-- Get the same element from another range as one element of the first range.
refPos :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [b] -> a -> b
refPos r1 r2 e1 = r2 !! (r1 `pos` e1)

letterNumber :: (Eq a, Char a) => a -> Int 
lettNumber x = refPos ['a'..'z'] [0..25] x
```

The text of the exact error is:

15:1 The type signature for letterNumber lacks an accompanying binding.

Originally the type signature I put was Char -> Int, but that didn't work (it said something about Eq, but I'm too new too Haskell to interpret it properly). So I changed the type signature to have an Eq class constraint. If someone can point out what is wrong or a workaround, it would be greatly appreciated as this is a doorstop problem to a project I'm working on.

Comment: This error is nearly always a typo in a function name in my experience! _Very_ occasionally it's because I forgot to write the function definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You provide a type signature for `letterNumber`, but then provide a binding for `lettNumber`. Note the missing `er`.

Just rename `lettNumber` to `letterNumber`, to match the spelling in the type signature.

---

Also, the correct type signature for `letterNumber` is

```
letterNumber :: Char -> Int
```

Comment: This is why I should be using an IDE. It's sad that I spent hours looking up technical documentation and even REWRITING the function and didn't find this. I feel bad for posting it now. Thank you.

Comment: I did way more stupid chit over and over again with or without a IDE. The only thing that is stupid is giving up. Here is my IDE setup in vim. https://gist.github.com/gertcuykens/1171609